# my update query didn't work on Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a table name "Category" which contains (cat_id, name, description). I can insert, retrieve, and delete without any problems. But when I update my Category, no data inserted in my database. I check my table and the result is nothing.

The POST model "Category_Model extends CI_Model":

```
public function custom_query($data)
    {
        $q = $this->db->query($data);
        return $q;
    }
```

The POST controller "Category extends CI_Controller":

```
public function edit_category()
    {
        $data['title'] = "Edit Category Page";

        $this->load->view('edit_category', $data);
    }

    public function update_category()
    {
        $id = $this->input->post('cat_id'); // I try $id = $this->uri->segment(3); but no result
        $name = $this->input->post('name');
        $desc = $this->input->post('description');

        $this->post_model->custom_query("update category set cat_name='".$name."', description='".$desc."' where cat_id='".$id."'"); // when I delete 'where cat_id='".$id."'' clause, all my records were changing/updating
        // I change to $this->db->where('cat_id', $id); $this->db->update('category'), but no result.

        redirect ('category/view_categories');
    }
```

Here is my EDIT CATEGORY view:

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>category/update_category" method="POST">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Edit Category</legend>
                <label for="cat">Name :</label>
                <input type="text" name="name"/>
                <label for="desc">Descriptions :</label>
                <textarea name="description" cols="40" rows="2"></textarea>
                <input type="submit" value="Update">
            </fieldset>
        </form>
```

Please anyone tell me what was wrong with my code? Thank in advance

best regards.

*note: I put 'database' in autoload config.

Comment: Why would you expect `$this->db->where('cat_id', $id); $this->db->update('category');` to work?

Comment: I follow CI active records query. Could you tell me how it'll be?

Comment: You're missing the `set` part. Try: `$this->db->update('category', array('cat_name'=>$name, etc...), array('cat_id'=>$id));` or just change your second part to `$this->db->update('category', $setarray);` See [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#update).

Comment: I use this custom query `$this->post_model->custom_query("update category set cat_name='".$name."', description='".$desc."' where cat_id='".$id."'");`. I think the goal is similar to CI User Guide

Comment: Yeah, yeah, that seems fine for a raw query (with all its security issues)... I was just refering to the part you commented out.

Comment: Hi, I chang my update model to this `function update($id, $data) {$this->db->where('cat_id', $id); $this->db->update('category', $data);}` and the result is Unknown column '0' in 'field list'UPDATE `category` SET `0` = 'Fiction', `1` = 'Lorem ipsum' WHERE `cat_id` = 0

Answer (score 0):

First of all, are you sure you writing table name correctly?

```
..."update kategori..."
```

If this is ok, try to output your query before sending it to database, like this:

```
$query = "update kategori set cat_name='".$name."', description='".$desc."' where cat_id='".$id."'";
error_log('My query: ' . print_r($query, true));
$this->post_model->custom_query($query);
```

Then, if you won't see any problems in that query, give it to us.

Comment: Hi Bandydan, I write correctly in my database "category". I just typo here. I updated my code above.

Comment: I follow your trick by putting this code "error_log('My query: ' . print_r($query, true));" (without double quotes) and the result is I didn't see anything

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your query might not be getting the `cat_id` as I don't see it anywhere in the passing view.  Try a hidden field in the HTML which contains the `cat_id`.  This might also be easier than trying to get it via URI segments.

Comment: Hi, I add hidden element like this "<input type="hidden" name="cat_id"/>" below form open, before fieldset, it's still not work

Comment: Are you populating the `value` attribute with the `cat_id` when you load the form with the category data?

Comment: yes, I give value to this `value="<?php echo $cat->cat_id ;?>">` from `foreach ($cats->result() as $cat)`

Comment: Try removing the quotes from `where cat_id='".$id."'");` as this is outputting `where cat_id='3'` (a string) instead of where cat_id=3` (an integer). From a readability/extendability perspective it would also be better to use Active Record to generate the query inside the model, and have individual functions for each type of call you want to make.

Answer (score 0):

You could be learn about CI models, it will simplify your life.
I believe with, for some reason, the redirect could be close your connection before the commit... It doesn't occur if you use the model object.

Comment: Yes, I will. But in this case, I need for someone guidance. If you have any suggestion or link it'll be welcome. :-)

Comment: please start testing my sample... I learned expanding some samples what I found.

Answer (score 0):

A little sample for models...

Create a class on application/models, like this

file "category_model.php"... attention for this name, because the CI is very restrictive with model name. Must by equal class name, but all lowercase.

```
class Category_model extends CI_Model {

// your fields
var $id = null;
var $name = null;

// call parent constructor... it's essential
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
}

// create a set function, for fill all fields directly from get or post
function set($data) {
    $this->id = isset($data['id']) ? $data['id'] : null;
    $this->name = isset($data['name']) ? $data['name'] : null;
}

// execute update on database
function update($id) {
    $this->db->update('category', $this, array('id' => $this->id));
}
}
```

on the controller, instance and invoke the model

```
$this->load->model('Category_Model', null, true);
$this->Category_Model->set($this->post());
$this->Category_Model->update();
```

after this, proceed you normal code.